# Wrinkles or cloth stimulation

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am making a pair of pants and I am wondering if sculpting or using cloth stimulation would be better for creating wrinkles.

Comment: "better" is quite subjective. If it will be animated, go with a cloth sim, ok? that way everything updates and you don't need to make a sculpt for every frame. else, just sculpt, it faster and easier, plus usually looks "better".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to animate your model you can try a simple trick: get a 2D image of a curtain with wrinkles, desaturate it, make it tileable and use it in "multiply" mode with the diffuse texture of your material. 
This makes fake wrinkles that very often do the job!